# "Edit" and "Close" Sign symbol while exporting Excel

Tags: yii2, kartik-v, editablegrid

When I try to export data in excel using "kartik\editable\Editable::widget" and "ExportMenu::widget" then "Edit" and "Close" sign symbols are also exported in my excel.

How to remove that "Edit" and "Close" Sign symbol while exporting Excel?

```
return kartik\editable\Editable::widget([
                'header'=>false,
                'name' => 'status',
                'size'=>'sm',
                'type'=>'primary',
                'placement'=>'right',
                'containerOptions'=>['class' => 'kv-sticky-column'],
                'contentOptions'=>['class' => 'kv-sticky-column'],
                'inputType'=>kartik\editable\Editable::INPUT_TEXT,
                'value'=>$location->getSummerValue($location['id']),
                'editableValueOptions'=>['asPopover' => false],
                'formOptions'=>[
                       'method' => 'post',
                       'id' => 'gv1_summer_'.$i.'_form_name',
                       'action' => ['/forward-price-curve/save-summer?location_id='.$location['id']]
                ],
                'options' => [
                       'id' => 'gv1_summer_'.$i.'_form_name',
                'pluginOptions'=>[
                       'autoclose'=>true,
                       'asPopover' => false,
                ]
                ],
                'submitButton'  => [
                    'class' => 'btn btn-sm btn-primary',
                    'icon'  => '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-save"></i>',
                ],
            ]);
```

Comment: what do you mean with "edit" and "close" symbol? Can you provide a screenshot?

Comment: this isnt the complete code you have submitted you should add all the code that you are using as you have `$i` inside the `formOptions` and `options`  which isnt resolvable from the current code piece

Comment: and are you using the editable inside the `EditableColumn` in `GridView` ?